# Can there a be a situation where two way propagation model is important in GHz range?

Tags: wireless, propagation

I assume that applicability different propagation model for wireless channel depends on the frequency of operation and the kind of obstacles or channel under consideration. My question is can anyone give me a practical situation when the two way ray model is applicable when the operating frequency is say 5 GHz? 
Link for the two way model is:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-ray_ground-reflection_model

Comment: There are many situations where it may be applicable. Provided the distance is much larger than the wavelength (almost always the case in wireless point-to-point communications) a ray model is appropriate. The model you gave is appropriate for this along as there are not many obstructions in the way, like say buildings.

Comment: @jramsay42 I am not asking about ray model: I am askng about two way model as in the link.

Comment: It's okay for any large distance, where there is little obstruction between the two antennas. I used to work at a company that made high-speed terrestrial microwave links to remote locations and that model was suitable.

Comment: @jramsay42 Do you remember the frequency of operation please?

Comment: 70-80 Ghz. The only real assumptions the model makes is that you are in the far field and there are only two major paths, which is true in an open environment.

Comment: Ricean and Raleigh Fading is more appropriate in home WiFi and downtown areas.

Comment: Two way Ray model? Wifi in Buildings with large steel structures, such as machines or tables in a kitchen or workshop, metal staircases in modern architecture, ... The key is that as soon as you don't have line-of-sight the model falls apart because all the other effects become very significant

Comment: @JorenVaes But the application you are taking about will have more than one reflection so, why this model will be valid?

Comment: Reminds of an incident my former boss solved when a microwave repeater installed in winter failed in spring because of snow on  a lake turning to water, such that the ground reflection cancelled out the direct path. (Rice fading in Ray model)

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 May I ask what was the frequency for the microwave repeater? I may be wrong but my feeling is that in high frequency there will be more reflection?

Comment: With smaller wavelengths there are more flat or moving wavy surfaces that can reflect higher f.  More scattering, more chance of Raleigh Fading.